# Change key binding for German umlauts in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, keyboard-layout

I like the use the German umlauts "ö", "Ö", "ä", and "Ä" on my keyboard for coding in VSCode, i.e., use these keys to type square and curly brackets. Here is what I tried in `keybindings.json`:

```
{ "key": "ö",           "command": "type", "args": { "text": "[" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "ä",           "command": "type", "args": { "text": "]" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "Shift+ö",     "command": "type", "args": { "text": "{" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "Shift+ä",     "command": "type", "args": { "text": "}" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "Alt-ö",       "command": "type", "args": { "text": "ö" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "Alt-ä",       "command": "type", "args": { "text": "ä" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "Alt-Shift+ö", "command": "type", "args": { "text": "Ö" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "Alt-Shift+ä", "command": "type", "args": { "text": "Ä" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

VSCode complains:

> You won't be able to produce this key combination under your current
>   keyboard layout.

Is there an easy way to teach VSCode to allow bindings for any key instead of just the predefined ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Gama11 for the hint regarding the UI. I tried it and got the keys `[Semicolon]`, `[Quote]`, and `[BracketLeft]`, for `ö`, `ä`, and `ü` for my German keyboard + layout.

Here is my working `keybindings.json`:

```json
    { "key": "[Semicolon]",           "command": "type", "args": { "text": "[" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
    { "key": "[Quote]",               "command": "type", "args": { "text": "]" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
    { "key": "Shift+[Semicolon]",     "command": "type", "args": { "text": "{" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
    { "key": "Shift+[Quote]",         "command": "type", "args": { "text": "}" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
    { "key": "Alt+[Semicolon]",       "command": "type", "args": { "text": "ö" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
    { "key": "Alt+[Quote]",           "command": "type", "args": { "text": "ä" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
    { "key": "Shift+Alt+[Semicolon]", "command": "type", "args": { "text": "Ö" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" },
    { "key": "Shift+Alt+[Quote]",     "command": "type", "args": { "text": "Ä" }, "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

It works perfectly for the mapped umlaut keys and does not interfere with the regular `;` and `"` keys.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Just one thing: in your posted code Ö and Ä are swapped in the last two lines. Can't edit it myself, because edits must be at least 6 characters (duh).

Comment: @Neonit that is intended. They "Ö" is left of the "Ä" and using the code above they are mapped correctly to `[` (left) and `]` (right) and `{` (left) and `}` (right)

Comment: No, I mean the extra binds for actually inserting an *Ä* and an *Ö* are swapped. You have bound `Alt+[Semicolon]` to *ö*, but `Shift+Alt+[Semicolon]` to *Ä*.

Comment:  You are right @Neonit! I actually never used that umlaut-fallback binding in VS Code, because I do not code in German . Fixed it now. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

These are allowed, the pre-defined "Toggle Integrated Terminal" shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd> after all. You just can't write the characters literally in JSON.

I usually prefer to use the JSON editor myself as well, but this is actually a case where the UI is quite helpful. In the "please enter desired key combination" popup, you can see that with a QWERTZ keyboard...

- ...`ö` turns in to `oem_3`
- ...`ä` turns in to `oem_7`
- ...`ü` turns in to `oem_1`